# Delta Lake OSS table large volume due to versioning

Tags: spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I have set up a Spark standalone cluster and use Spark Structured Streaming to write data from Kafka to multiple Delta Lake tables - simply stored in the file system. So there are multiple writes per second.
After running the pipeline for a while, I noticed that the tables require a large amount of storage on Disk. Some tables require 10x storage compared to the sources.

I investigated the Delta Lake table versioning. When I `DESCRIBE` a selected table, it's stated that the `sizeInBytes` is actually around 10 GB, although the corresponding folder on the disk takes over 100 GB.

```
DESCRIBE DETAIL delta.`/mnt/delta/bronze/algod_indexer_public_txn_flat`
```

So I set the following properties:

```
ALTER TABLE delta.`/mnt/delta/bronze/algod_indexer_public_txn_flat` 
SET TBLPROPERTIES ('delta.logRetentionDuration'='interval 24 hours', 'delta.deletedFileRetentionDuration'='interval 1 hours')
```

and then performed a VACUUM:

```
VACUUM delta.`/mnt/delta/bronze/algod_indexer_public_txn_flat`
```

But still, after several days, the size on the disk stays at around 100GB. Altough constantly performing a VACUUM.
How can I overcome this issue?

- Spark 3.2.1
- Delta Lake 1.2.0

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Looks like when I manually delete the json logs in _delta_log the VACUUM actually cleans old versions, so I assume some of the properties are not applied?

Comment: do you have append-only workload?

Comment: yes spark writes the stream in outputMode("append"). I do not delete or updated any rows.

Comment: In this case the versioning overhead is very small…

Comment: What could be another possible cause for the large disk overhead?